# Run apache in default port

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

I have ubuntu 11.04 and my apache was running on localhost but I tried to install varnish and have a ride on varnish . So I followed [this tutorial](http://www.debiantutorials.com/installing-and-configuring-varnish-http-accelerator/) and made changes. But after install I saw apache is not running on localhost. When I gave localhost:8008 it was okay. Now I removed varnish and made changes to the port  8008 to 80, but still apache is running on 8008 port.My default sites configuration is like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I just want to run apache in default port.
When I made the apche restart it showed an error like this

```
[warn] NameVirtualHost *:8008 has no VirtualHosts
httpd (pid 12174) already running
```

Comment: More of the httpd.conf would help, somewhere along the lines should be a directive setting the port to 8008. Might very well be in an `Include` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ihis is the file you are looking for:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

In this file, change `LISTEN 80`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your Apache config is the line:

```
Listen 8008
```

That specifies the port Apache listens on.

Comment: I searched it but there was nothing like that